# Unable to Integrate JMeter & Prometheus

Tags: testing, jmeter, integration, prometheus, grafana

Below is my Configuration in Prometheus.yml

[image: Prometheus.yml File]

I am Unable to see the Metrics in Browser with localhost:9270 or 127.0.0.1:9270 or with myip:9270. However the same way its working for WMI Exporter (9182) & Prometheus (9090)

Error Faced :- **Get "http://localhost:9270/metrics": dial tcp [::1]:9270: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.**.
I have even Tried to remove firewall restrictions. Still Facing Same Issue.. Can anyone Help me Out?

Answer (score 0):

When you cannot open the metrics page in the browser and get this error, Jmeter did not open the port 9270. With `netstat -anp` you can check which port its listening too.